# Method for calculating the angle between two vectors throwing up an error if the vectors are identical?

Tags: python, numpy, math, vector, angle

I feel as if this should be fairly straightforward but I have been staring at code and am now being stupid. I have a method that takes two input 3D vectors and returns the angle between them in degrees.

The method is as follows:

```
def CalculateAngleBetweenVector(vector, vector2):

    dp = np.dot(vector, vector2)

    maga = math.sqrt((vector[0] ** 2) + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2)
    magb = math.sqrt((vector2[0] ** 2) + vector2[1] ** 2 + vector2[2] ** 2)
    magc = maga * magb

    dpmag = dp / magc

    angleindeg = ((math.acos(dpmag)) * 180) / math.pi

    return angleindeg
```

Currently I have two identical vectors going in to test something else and have realised this method errors when I do. The two vectors are:

```
[ 0.38154065 -0.38688849 -0.83949034]
```

The method I use fro working out the unit vectors for the inputs is:

```
UnitVector = Vector / np.linalg.norm(Vector)
```

Just incase something is wrong here.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thanks

edit:

sorry the vector going in is actually (0.38154065, -0.38688849, -0.83949034) I just copied the terminal print line. The error is a math domain error.

edit2:

```
Error traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file path info that contains personal info Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/WORK/Code1/CompareAnglesBetweenProteinAndMembane.py", line 261, in <module>
    angle = CalculateAngleBetweenVector(ProteinRotatedUV, MemRotatedUV)
  File "file path info that contains personal info Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/WORK/Code1/CompareAnglesBetweenProteinAndMembane.py", line 167, in CalculateAngleBetweenVector
    angleindeg = ((math.acos(dpmag)) * 180) / math.pi
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Your code is working fine for me (Python 3.6) if I run your provided list (adding the necessary commas) through the function

Comment: Missing commas in Vector definition?

Comment: @LukasThaler I have added a bit of extra info. It is a math domain error I am getting.

Comment: @Lesiak I have added a bit of info. That was copy and pasted from the terminal and is the output of the unit vector code.

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback (including the line your code fails and the exact error)?

Comment: @LukasThaler I have added the full traceback as a second edit.

Comment: Your dpmag is outside the domain (arguments allowed for) acos function. Acos is defined only for arguments -1<x<1. What is the value of your dpmag(it is 1.0 on my machine)

Comment: A math domain error resulting from the `math.acos`-function indicates that `dpmag` was outside the [-1, 1] range, possibly due to rounding issues

Comment: @LukasThaler Thank you my value is coming out to 1.0000000000000002. I guess I should only take the first 3 significant figures or something.

Comment: @Lesiak Thank you my value is coming out to 1.0000000000000002. I guess I should only take the first 3 significant figures or something

Comment: Use `try` / `except ValueError:` to handle the `Exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem stems from rounding errors in floating-point arithmetics (argument for `acos` slightly out of range).

I would consider the following changes:

1. Use simpler formula

```
angle = acos(dot(A,B) / (|A|* |B|))
```

2. If the argument to the arccos is slightly above 1.0 or below -1.0, just round it. You don't need to do that if the argument is in range.
3. Normalization only helps if vectors are close to [0,0,0], or have very big entries - the calculation is more numerically stable. If neither is the case in your app, consider removing normalization.